# Small highlighter effect

Tags: css

I want to get a css effect like a highlighter

[Example of highlighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cy2P.png)

I found some answers like [Pen highlighter effect in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451683/pen-highlighter-effect-in-css).
But how could I get this highlighter effect in smaller as you can see in the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an ::after pseudo element to do the highlight.
Here is an example:

```css
.highlight {
  position: relative;
}


.highlight::after {
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #9bffb0a6;
  z-index: -1;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div><span class="highlight">Cloud Native</span>: Cloud Training, Cloud Development, Cloud Architecture, Cloud Assesment....</div>
```

Just the .highlight class for any text you want to highlight.

Comment: Of course you can change the background-color to change highlight color, and the height property to change how high the highlight is.

Comment: I have another issue - I would like to make the green darker when the link is hovered. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can do something like:
.highlight:hover::after {
  background-color: #63b574ad;
}

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```css
.underline span {
 display: inline-block;
 background-position-y: -0%;
 background-image: linear-gradient( transparent 50%, #0095ff 50%);
 transition: background .3s ease;
 background-size: 2px;
 background-size: auto 175%;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<p class="underline">
  This sentence has <span>Highlighted Text</span> in the middle.
</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP requested. This highlights the whole text, not just the bottom