# Rounded highlighter marker effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve the following effect, where the green marker in the background should also respect line wraps. This means that in contrast to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451683/pen-highlighter-effect-in-css), the marker effect should not span the entire height of the text, but just the bottom part:

[image]

Currently, I already managed to do it like this, but the top edges of the underline are not rounded here, because the `border-radius` obviously cannot affect those. How can I fix this?

```css
.highlighted {
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%,
    rgba(154, 216, 215, 1) 60%,
    rgba(154, 216, 215, 1) 100%
  );
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  max-width: 100vw;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlighted">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient
</div>
```

Comment: Use a pseudo element like `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple background:

```css
.highlighted {
  --c:rgb(154, 216, 215); /* the color */
  --r:12px; /* the size/radius */
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,#0000) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,#0000) bottom right;
  background-size:var(--r) var(--r),calc(100% - var(--r)) var(--r);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlighted">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient
</div>

<div class="highlighted" style="--c:red;--r:16px">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient
</div>
```

Another syntax with less gradients:

```css
.highlighted {
  --c:rgb(154, 216, 215); /* the color */
  --r:12px; /* the size/radius */
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,#0000) 
     0 100%/var(--r) var(--r) round no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) 
     bottom/calc(100% - var(--r)) var(--r) no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlighted">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient
</div>

<div class="highlighted" style="--c:red;--r:16px">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* background-color: bisque; */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p{
  font-size:5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: fit-content;
}

p::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #dadada;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```